# Why does servlet name stay in url after RequestDispatcher.forward?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am making a JSP/Servlet web app which starts with log in page.
After user enters log in information, a servlet, called `LoginServlet`, processes the data and if the log in is successful the servlet redirects user to `MainPage.jsp` like this:

```
RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("MainPage.jsp");
rd.forward(request,response);
```

It works. It takes me to MainPage.jsp, only the URL is **NOT**:

```
http://localhost:8080/RestauRec/MainPage.jsp
```

it **is**:

```
http://localhost:8080/RestauRec/LoginServlet
```

It is not an actual problem, but still, I want to know why this is and how can I change this?

**Note:** I don't know if it matters or not but, in the `action` attribute of the `form` element (in the log in page) I place `LoginServlet`. Like this:

```
<form action="LoginServlet" method="POST">
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Read this http://javapapers.com/jsp/difference-between-forward-and-sendredirect/

Comment: because this is how `forward()` works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`forward()`  method won't change the url. [`sendRedirect()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#sendRedirect(java.lang.String)) in `HttpServletResponse` do change the url as well.

```
response.sendRedirect("MainPage.jsp");
```

Remember that a new request gets hit to the container when you do redirect. That means all the previous data vanishes and you'll get a brand new request.

Comment: Yes, I know. But does it make sense to use 'sendRedirect()' within same web application? As far as I know 'sendRedirect()' should be used to for accessing remote resources.

Comment: @DjolePi Why not. It meant for that :)

Answer (score 3):

`forward` is an action that happens within a single request-response cycle. It uses the forward-to resource to complete the response.

Your browser sends a single request to `/someUrl` and your server handles it, returning a response.

> It is not an actual problem, but still, I want to know why this is and how can I change this?

You'd have to make your client, the browser, send a different request to another URL, possibly because of a redirect.

Comment: +1 forward is done on server, and it does not ask the client browser to send another request (change the URL), if you need changing the URL too , use .redirect()